# Why does release:prepare change versions back to SNAPSHOT?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the maven-release-plugin and I'm noticing that it appears to change the released version BACK to -SNAPSHOT at the end.

Here's the command line args that I'm passing to maven:

```
--batch-mode release:prepare -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -Darguments="-DskipTests -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmaven.javadoc.failOnError=false"
```

Everything appears to go well - and I notice a commit and a push from the plugin where all of the proper version numbers are indeed updated to NOT have the -SNAPSHOT.

```
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? myProject/pom.xml.releaseBackup
```

I see a few of these warnings ^ in the log file (not sure if this is relevant, but appears to be related to the release plugin)

Finally I see that the plugin modifies the POMs again:

```
[INFO] Transforming 'myProject POM'...
[INFO]   Updating my-project to 6.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Following this the plugin makes and pushes a commit with the following:

```
[maven-release-plugin] rollback changes from release preparation of myProject-6.2
```

Why is this last bit happening?

I don't understand the lifecycle of release:prepare or release:perform.  Why does all of my code appear to be built twice?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, release:prepare

- Updates the POM files to the version that was specified
- performs the build, which runs the tests
- performs other validations (ie, no dependencies to SNAPSHOT artifacts)
- Commits the changes (which should be restricted to the POM files and their versions)
- Tags the source that was just committed
- Updates the pom files back to the nominated SNAPSHOT version
- Commits those changes

Note: I'm not sure if that's the specific order.  The above list is not an exhaustive list, it's just my recollection.

At this point, the  release doesn't exist.  That's what release:perform does.  Release:perform checks out the code against the TAG and builds the artifacts against the tagged source.

This is why release:prepare moves it back to the snapshot version.  It's simply preparing the source to have a release built against it.  Developers working on that branch, once the tag is cut, can continue to commit changes without affecting release:perform.  It also allows a release to be re-cut at a later date, as it is built against the tag.

Of course, there are variations to this plugin which is documented.  But, as I understand it, this is a common workflow for this.

Comment: This perfectly explains the reasoning. Your sentence about release:perform also clears up why I'm seeing the code built twice. I came upon a "gotcha" situation where the release:perform has this "workingDirectory" parameter.  This is where the TAG is checked out.  By default this is: ${project.build.directory}/checkout.  This was causing an issue for me because my maven build calls an ant script.  I am attempting to work though the issue now. Wasn't aware that the plugin would check out code somewhere I didn't expect it to.